# Sheldon Ross Conditional Probability Question 31

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Twenty persons are attending a meeting in a hall, 8 of whom left the hall and have returned at least once so far. Four persons have just left and are coming back. This coincides with the selection of a subcommittee of 4 persons who will be chosen by everyone. What is the probability
that all subcommittee members will have never left the hall?

**Answer**: 0.0125

**My Approach**
Let $E_{x}$ be the event that $x$ persons out of $4$ who are outside are from out of the ones that have gone back and came back at least once
Then out of 8 people, $8-x$ remain back for choosing the subcommittee. And out of remaining 16, $8+x$ persons would have never gone out.

Let $N\equiv$ the event that the selection of 4 people does not contain from the 16 who stayed back contains people who never went out.

Since $E_{i}$s are mutually exclusive and $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{4}E_{i}=S$, the sample space, we have,

$P(N)=\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{4}P(N|E_{x})P(E_{x})$

Since $P(E_{x})=\displaystyle\frac{\binom{8}{x}\binom{12}{4-x}}{\binom{20}{4}}$
and $P(N|E_{x})=\displaystyle\frac{\binom{8+x}{4}}{\binom{16}{4}}$, we have

$P(N)=\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^{4}\displaystyle\frac{\binom{8+x}{4}\binom{8}{x}\binom{12}{4-x}}{\binom{16}{4}\binom{20}{4}}$.

But this is giving me the answer 33/323 (Using PARI/GP CAS).

*Please review my approach and suggest any corrections.*

Comment: You asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612494/conditional-probability-problem-from-sheldon-ross) before. At the time, it was pointed out to you that the problem is not clearly phrased.  There are important, and non-obvious, assumptions that you need to make before it becomes answerable.  What assumptions are you making?

Comment: Sorry, in $P(N|E_{x})$, it should be $\displaystyle\binom{16}{4}$.
The assumptions I am making are: (1) $x$ persons out of 8 initial ones who have gone out and came backs are in common with 4 people who are still out (2) 16 people staying back are to be chosen for a subcommittee of 4 people

And yes, I asked before. But this time, I have given it more thought :)